# Extending JCheckbox through multiple classes

Tags: java, swing, extends, jcheckbox

I am trying to create a character creator using `JCheckBox`. I have created all my classes, however, when extending each class into the next, I am unable to see the return results for the prior class. For example, I have a `Gender` class and a `Race` class. The `Gender` class has two check boxes, one for male and one for female. By itself, this class works. However, when I use the `Race` class to extend the `Gender` class, everything shows up, but clicking the boxes does not output into the `JTextField`. Below is my Code for `Gender` and for `Race`.

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
public class Gender extends JFrame implements ItemListener  
{

   FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();  
   JLabel label = new JLabel("What gender would you like to be?");


   JCheckBox male = new JCheckBox("Male", false);  
   JCheckBox female = new JCheckBox("Female", false);  

   JTextField GENDER = new JTextField(12);  

   String output, insChosen;  
   String Gender = "";  

   public Gender()  
   {  
      super("Character Creation");  
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
      label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 15));  


      GENDER.setText("Gender" + Gender + ".");  
      male.addItemListener(this);  
      female.addItemListener(this);  


      add(label);  
      add(male);  
      add(female);  
      add(GENDER);  


   }  

   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)  
   {  
      Object source = event.getSource();  
      int selects = event.getStateChange();  


      if(male.isSelected())  
         Gender = "Male";  
      else  
         if(female.isSelected())  
            Gender = "Female";  

      GENDER.setText("Gender: " + Gender);  
   }  

   public static void main(String[] args)  
   {  
      final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;  
      final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;  
      Gender frame = new Gender();  
      frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);  
      frame.setVisible(true);  

   }  

}
```

and here is the code for Race.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Race extends Gender
{
   FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
   JLabel label = new JLabel("What race would you like to play as?");


   JCheckBox elf = new JCheckBox("Elf", false);
   JCheckBox troll = new JCheckBox("Troll", false);
   JCheckBox human = new JCheckBox("Human", false);
   JCheckBox dwarf = new JCheckBox("Dwarf", false);
   JCheckBox orc = new JCheckBox("Orc", false);

   JTextField RACE = new JTextField(12);

   String output, insChosen;
   String Race = "";


   public Race()
   {

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 15));


      RACE.setText("Race" + Race + ".");


      elf.addItemListener(this);
      troll.addItemListener(this);
      human.addItemListener(this);
      dwarf.addItemListener(this);
      orc.addItemListener(this);


      add(label);
      add(elf);
      add(troll);
      add(human);
      add(dwarf);
      add(orc);
      add(RACE);

   }

   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
   {
      Object source = event.getSource();
      int select = event.getStateChange();

      if(elf.isSelected())
         Race = "Elf";
      else
         if(troll.isSelected())
            Race = "Troll";
         else
            if(human.isSelected())
               Race = "Human";
            else
               if(dwarf.isSelected())
                  Race = "Dwarf";
               else
                  if(orc.isSelected())
                     Race = "Orc";
       RACE.setText("Race: " + Race);

   }



   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      final int FRAME_WIDTH = 350;
      final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 300;
      Race frame = new Race();
      frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Each work seperately, but will not work in conjuction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried calling `super.itemStateChanged` in the `Race` class

Comment: Just curious, what exactly are you trying to achieve by making `Race` extends `Gender`? Seems like to me, you are improperly using inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've overridden `itemStateChanged` in `Race`, which was inherited from `Gender` but failed to call `super.itemStateChanged`, it is no longer been called in `Gender`.

Add `super.itemStateChanged(event);` to `Race`'s `itemStateChanged` method, for example:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
    super.itemStateChanged(event);
```

Consider using `JRadioButton`s, grouped through the use of a `ButtonGroup` for the gender, as it's (typically) and either/or selection, maybe even a `JComboBox` which will limit what the user can select

I would avoid extending directly from `JFrame` as you've automatically limited any future expansion or use of the class.

Instead, consider using a `JPanel` instead.  This would mean you wouldn't "need" to extend from `Gender` but could simply "include" within the `Race` class.

I'd also encourage you to separate the model/data from the UI itself, so the UI modifies the model and responds to changes made to the model, but that's just me

Comment: How would I save the variable from Gender if I wanted to output it in race? For example if i put a JTextField that read               JTextField Last = new JTextField(30);                  Last.setText("Your chosen gender is " + Gender + ".")

Comment: You would just have done getters and setters in Gender, but if you were using a model approach, you supply that information directly to/from the model us jnr setters and getters